# Receiving Error: Notice: Undefined variable – but already defined

Tags: php, html

I dont know what im doing wrong. But i get this

> **Notice: Undefined variable: num1** in D:\Programs\XAMPP\htdocs\homework\addsub.php on line 15`

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        $num1=$_POST['t1'];
        $num2=$_POST['t2'];
        if ($_POST['sub']=="+") {
            $res= $num1 + $num2;
        }
        elseif($_POST['sub']=="-"){
            $res = $num1-$num2;
        }
    }
 ?>
<form action="addsub.php"  method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="t1" value="<?php echo $num1;?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2" value="<?php echo $num2;?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="res" value="<?php echo $res;?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="+">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="-">
</form>
```

When I use `$num1` or `$num2` in textbox values, it shows error. One of my friends used this same code on his laptop but he is using much older version of Xampp. It works fine but later versions of Xampp gives this error. I am using *Xampp v3.2.1*.

Comment: as [masterFly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39824665/1028804) has said your problem is that `$num1` only exists if `$_POST['sub']` is set so you need to be setting `$num1` and `$num2` as some sort of default value before your if statement or use an else for when `isset($_POST['sub'])`. because it's a notice it could be other versions of Xampp that you've tried on have had error reporting turned off so it wouldn't be anything to do with the Xampp version but rather the PHP settings for those instances of Xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use isset to check variable exist or not.

example

```
<input type="text" name="t1" value="<?php echo isset($num1)?$num1:""; ?>"><br>
```

Comment: how does isset($num1)?$num1:""; work? Can you please explain.

Comment: its checking that if $num1 isset then echo its value otherwise echo blank value and if your variable is not set then php code never gives you error . always use this method when u pass value in input fields. and isset($num1)?$num1:""; is the turnary operator means before ? is our condition that we need to check and after ? is the value that will be echo if condition is true otherwise the value after : will be echo.

Answer (score 4):

Or initialize the variable if it doesn't exist, like so:

```
<?php
if (!isset($num1)) {
    $num1 = '';
}
```

Then your HTML could remain unchanged.

The reason I recommend this approach is that it creates clean code - the HTML will always display the value of **$num1** and if you choose to initialize it to a different value later, it should be easier to find in the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You set the `$num1` variable only when,

```
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
```

So, if the `$_POST['sub']` is not there the variable is undefined!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, which may help you:

```
<?php 
    var $res="";
    var $num1="";
    var $num2="";
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        $num1=$_POST['t1'];
        $num2=$_POST['t2'];
        if ($_POST['sub']=="+") {
            $res= $num1 + $num2;
        }
        elseif($_POST['sub']=="-"){
            $res = $num1-$num2;
        }
    }
 ?>

<form action="addsub.php"  method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="t1" value="<?php echo $num1;?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2" value="<?php echo $num2;?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="res" value="<?php echo $res;?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="+">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="-">
</form>
```